# Moving VM from default location to LVM Volume Group

Tags: kvm

I have debian as my host OS. Using virt-manager I have successfully installed a guest OS but its virtual machine files are in the default `/var/lib/libvirt/images/`.

I have unused partitions that I would like to move this (and future guest OS's) to. How do I proceed after creating the partition using fdisk?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store your KVM/QEMU disk images in the unused partitions you have a couple of options:

- [partition-based storage pool](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Storage_Pools-Creating-File_Systems.html)
- [LVM-based volumes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Storage_Pools-Creating-LVM.html)

Either way, you'll need to create a new storage pool; which you can do with virt-manager. But the options above work differently.

The partition-based approach is actually a misleading name. You'd think it uses a partition per disk image, but in fact it formats the partition with the filesystem of your choice, mounts it, and stores the disk images on the filesystem. It's really no different than the default storage volume `/var/lib/libvirt/images/` in functionality.

The LVM-based storage pool takes a different approach. It creates a logical volume for each disk image. So there's a 1:1 mapping between VM disk image and LVM volume.

Once you have your storage pool you can use it when creating new VMs. As for moving the existing images, it's straight-forward with the "partition-based" approach: copy the images and then modify the VM to point to the copied image. For LVM... I'm honestly not sure. A simple `dd` to the logical volume may work.

Comment: Just to confirm, I just did a `dd` of a `qcow2`  image to a new logical volume and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I created a new directory on the free disk, then moved the /var/lib/libvirt/images/* files there, and then simply made a symbolic link with "`ln -s /newdisk/newdir /var/lib/libvirt/images`"